# how to add object to a keyframe range?

Tags: animation

lets assume we have an iron man pointing his hand to a target and shooting few frames later as shown in the picture below:

[image]

frame 0 to 10 he will point frame 11 to 15 he will shoot, which is just a long cube with one larger face to give idea or a laser projectile

how can I add the projectile cube only on frame 11?
I don't what it to exist before that

thanks

Comment: You can also use particle system to generate the object at a specific time and kill or destroy it at a specific time. Particle system would be the way professional animator would handle the requirement at hand, since modifying the animation would be lesser of an issue. You will only need to key in your start and end frame in the particle system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could keyframe the visibility and the renderability of the shot object in the outliner (<kbd>RMB</kbd> over the icons and *insert keyframe*:

[image]

- Disable visibility and renderability in frame 0 and add keyframe
- Enable in frame 11 and add keyframe

Answer (score 4):

An easy way you can do this is kind of cheating, but it does work. On frame 11, set a location keyframe on your laser object. On frame 15, do the same. On frame 10 and 16, move the laser object along any axis an absurd distance away. 9999999 blender units is usually enough. that way, on frames 11-15, your laser will appear in front of the weapon, and it will vanish again at frame 16. This is an alternative method. the one [stacker gave in his answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43991/5426) is the proper way to do it.

[image]